# MS Edge showing file origin as "about:blob"

Tags: java, rest, microsoft-edge

I have a rest service to download a file, and I have a small problem with Edge. When I sent GET request to get the file the browser, displays the following confirmation dialog.

[image]

The 'From' attribute should point to whatever the current host name, but instead, it says 'about:blob'.

I feel like I'm missing some headers but cannot figure out which one. 
Here are my request and response headers (as captured from the dev tools):

```
 *  REQUEST  *
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
cache-control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
content-type: application/json
Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXX
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393

 *  RESPONSE  *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization, x-requested-with, content-encoding, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="C:UsersmikhailDocumentsdesktop.ini"
Content-Length: 402
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 04 Apr 2017 03:42:11 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: WildFly/10
x-filename: C:\Users\mikhail\Documents\desktop.ini
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
```

Any idea how to tell Edge to use the hostname instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved in Edge browser version 40.15